# PostgreSQL 11 master-master replication between docker hosts

Tags: postgresql, docker, replication

Im using PostgreSQL 11 docker image, i need to make a master-master replication between 2 servers that has docker on them for clustering purposes.(its going to be 2 main cluster servers with 1 server for nginx to redirect between them in case of a shutdown \ maintenance)

I couldn't find a good guide for master-master on docker containers between 2 different hosts.
should i use docker-swarm ? is there another good way for this ?

my docker-compose:

```
postgres:
        image: postgres:11.9
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
                - /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
                - ./posrgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro

        environment:
                - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
                - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

Comment: Please lookup **repmgr** documentation.

Comment: Postgres has no built-in master-master replication.

Comment: You could use logical replication: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-high-availability-master-slave-master-master-architectures